# Typescript/Angular2 getUserMedia is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, quaggajs

I have an Ionic 2 App which uses [QuaggaJS Github](https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS) to Stream the Camera to my View (Div Container) like Snapchat to scan QR Codes. In the browser, it all works like a charm but, the moment it gets built as APK or IPA file I'm getting the Error:

```
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(76955)] "Error: getUserMedia is not defined"
```

I used ADB and a Virutal Android Device to get the logcat output.
**Important Info: Yes I have Camera Permission!**

Just in case you cant visualize what I'm talking about ,here is a Screenshot of my Page View:
[image: Screenshot of Scanner]

And this is my Typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import Quagga from 'quagga';
declare var Quagga:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-scanner',
  templateUrl: 'scanner.html',
})
export class Scanner implements OnInit {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public menu: MenuController) {
  }
   ngOnInit() {
     //WARNING:
     //Error: Types of property 'lift' are incompatible -> means
     //that the used typescript version is too high. Works with: 2.3.4 atm

     Quagga.init({
         inputStream : {
             name : "Live",
             type : "LiveStream",
             constraints: {
               width:  window.innerWidth,
               height: window.innerHeight,
               facingMode: "environment"
             },
             area: {
                top: "0%",
                right: "0%",
                left: "0%",
                bottom: "0%"
            },
            // Or '#yourElement' (optional)
           target: document.querySelector('#scanner')
         },
         locator: {
           patchSize: "medium",
           halfSample: true
         },
         numOfWorkers: (navigator.hardwareConcurrency ? navigator.hardwareConcurrency : 4),
         decoder : {
          //Change Reader for the right Codes
          readers: [ "code_128_reader",
                     "ean_reader",
                     "ean_8_reader",
                     "code_39_reader",
                     "code_39_vin_reader",
                     "codabar_reader",
                     "upc_reader",
                     "upc_e_reader",
                     "i2of5_reader" ],
         },
         locate: true
       }, function(err) {
           if (err) {
               console.log(err);
               return
           }
           console.log("Initialization finished. Ready to start");
           Quagga.start();
       });
       // Make sure, QuaggaJS draws frames an lines around possible
        // barcodes on the live stream
        Quagga.onProcessed(function(result) {
            var drawingCtx = Quagga.canvas.ctx.overlay,
                drawingCanvas = Quagga.canvas.dom.overlay;

            if (result) {
                if (result.boxes) {
                    drawingCtx.clearRect(0, 0, parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute("width")), parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute("height")));
                    result.boxes.filter(function (box) {
                        return box !== result.box;
                    }).forEach(function (box) {
                        Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(box, {x: 0, y: 1}, drawingCtx, {color: "green", lineWidth: 2});
                    });
                }

                if (result.box) {
                    Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.box, {x: 0, y: 1}, drawingCtx, {color: "#00F", lineWidth: 2});
                }

                if (result.codeResult && result.codeResult.code) {
                    Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.line, {x: 'x', y: 'y'}, drawingCtx, {color: 'red', lineWidth: 3});
                }
            }
        });
      // Once a barcode had been read successfully, stop quagga and
      // close the modal after a second to let the user notice where
      // the barcode had actually been found.
      Quagga.onDetected(function(result) {
        if (result.codeResult.code){
        // Was passieren soll wenn ein Code gescannt wurde
        //  $('#scanner_input').val(result.codeResult.code);
        }
      });
   }
   ionViewWillLeave(){
     Quagga.stop();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this may be the dumpest answer I have ever written, but I sloved my problem by myself. 
Sometimes the easiest things are the reasons of weird errors.

Well as it states [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html) **getUserMedia() is aviable on Android 5.0+**, 
but I worked the whole time on Android 4.4.2 Device. After an Update all worked fine.

> **This release** introduces the PermissionRequest class, which **allows your app to grant the WebView** permission to access protected resources like the **camera and microphone**, **through web APIs such as getUserMedia()**. Your app must have the appropriate Android permissions for these resources in order to grant the permissions to the WebView.

I've never had 3 days as much wasted as with this error.
Cheers

Comment: @JGFMK anyways I have to thank you for your help and honord you with 50 rep. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

From [here](https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS) it states:

> 1) Important: Accessing getUserMedia requires a secure origin in most
>   browsers, meaning that **http://** can only be used on **localhost**. All
>   other hostnames need to be served via **https://**. You can find more
>   information in the [Chrome M47 WebRTC Release Notes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/sq5CVmY69sc).
>
> Feature-detection of getUserMedia
>
> 2) **Every browser seems to differently implement the
>   mediaDevices.getUserMedia API. Therefore it's highly recommended to
>   include webrtc-adapter in your project.**
>
> Here's how you can test your browser's capabilities:
>
> 3) **if (navigator.mediaDevices && typeof
>   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === 'function') {   // safely
>   access `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` }** The above condition
>   evaluates to:
>
> Browser   result
>   Edge        true 
>   Chrome      true 
>   Firefox     true 
>   IE 11       false 
>   Safari iOS  false

So can you:

1. Confirm whether you are using https
2. You have included [webrtc-adapter](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter)
3. Whether Android passes the condition check.

Link for others on [MediaDevices.getUserMedia from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

Comment: I did what you said but i always getting the error: `TypeError: Cannot call method 'enumerateDevices' of undefined`. Undefinded means = mediaDevices. Because this is the code line which triggers the error: `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();`. So still after including webrtc my Ionic 2 project cant find mediaDevices or getUserMedia.

Comment: info: added question to the ionic forum: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/getusermedia-is-not-defined-stackoverflow-added/100238

Comment: That webrtc project was supposed to create shims.. The Chrome message in your question.. Is that coming from an Android device, or via 
 Chrome on your development machine? Only this is the code that was supposed to enable functionality for you to use. https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/blob/master/src/js/chrome/getusermedia.js

Comment: I have sloved my Problem by myselfe. Look at the answers.